# css cursor: pointer doesn't work on div element

Tags: css, angular, sass

I'm working on an Angular app and I'm trying to make a div have the 'cursor: pointer' class. For some weird reason it doesn't seem to work.

I've checked multiple similar questions and answers on stackoverflow, I also googled a lot for an answer, but none solved the issue. I've even read about a solution as ridiculous as 'closing Photoshop on your desktop' to solve the problem.

I wonder whether this could be a bug of some sort.

So this is a part of my template:

```
<div class="social-icons_container"
     fxFlex
     [fxLayout]="direction"
     fxLayoutAlign="space-between">

  <div class="icon_container"
      (click)="onFacebookClicked()">

    <svg class="icon"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         viewBox="0 0 128 128"
         [ngStyle]="{ 'width': logoSize }">

     ...and so on ...
```

And here is the SCSS file:

```
.social-icons_container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1.2rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

    .icon_container {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }



<div _ngcontent-c12=""
     class="social-icons_container"
     fxflex=""
     fxlayoutalign="space-between"
     ng-reflect-fx-layout="row"
     ng-reflect-fx-layout-align="space-between"
     ng-reflect-fx-flex=""
     style="flex-direction: row;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     display: flex;
     place-content: stretch space-between;
     align-items: stretch;
     flex: 1 1 0%;">

<div _ngcontent-c12=""
     class="icon_container">

<svg _ngcontent-c12=""
     class="icon"
     viewBox="0 0 112.196 112.196"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"

 ...and so on...
```

**UPDATE**: I've temporarily solved it with an ugly workaround - I've added an [ngStyle] that sets 'cursor' to 'pointer'. I'd appreciate if somebody posted an answer with a reasonable & clean solution. I'll be waiting :)

Comment: Is the specificity correct ? As in is `social-icons_container` style working as expected.

Comment: @ashish.gd yes, it is. I can set any property on the social-icons_container and they work. I've just tested it positive with 'background-color'.

Comment: Can you share the generated DOM tree for `social-icons_container`. I am interested to see if `icon_container` div is the direct child of `social-icons_container` or does it have any interim wrapper div with `ng-content*` classes as I am not well versed with Angular Flex Layout.

Comment: It'd be easy to verify your issue if you share a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) :)

Comment: @kukkuz I don't know how to share stuff on stackblitz :( Do I need to share the whole app or is it possible to share just the relevant parts?

Comment: @ashish.gd where do I share the DOM tree? Is it allowed in the comments or should I rather edit my question?

Comment: Sure, you can edit the question.

Comment: See this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vgkmc5

Comment: @kukkuz I know what stackblitz is :) but I don't know how to use it...

Comment: UPDATE: I've temporarily solved it with an ugly workaround - I've added an [ngStyle] that sets 'cursor' to 'pointer'. I'd appreciate if somebody posted an answer with a reasonable & clean solution. I'll be waiting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help attempts guys, but I found out what the problem was.
I had some 'leftover' code in my scss file with the same class resetting the cursor pointer to its default.

```
.icon_container {
   cursor: default;
}
```

It was my stupid mistake - I removed the code block and now it works with the following:

```
.icon_container {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way may be it will fix your problem

```
.social-icons_container {
      width: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 1.2rem;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;

        .icon {
          cursor: pointer;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a Stackblitz using your code except the `svg` part.

> It is working correctly as long as the `icon_container` gets
>   valid dimensions.

You can try updating it with your actual svg and test it.

Please refer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6xlagm

Comment: what do you mean by 'valid dimensions'?

Comment: As in a `width` and `height` property. In the Stackblitz example it is getting the width and height based on its child `svg` elements.